# Should I use "or" or "and" in "there is no university or college"?

Tags: conjunctions

I want to say that in my city there is **no university**. In addition, there is **no college**. Which sentence is correct?

> 1. In my city there is no university **and** college
> 2. In my city there is no university **or** college

I know it might be very basic but I really hadn't given it much thought! Now I feel I have been using these conjunctions very recklessly so far! I have a gut feeling that the second one is correct. I just feel better when I say "university or college", but I do not know why this is!

Comment: If you are familiar with mathematical logic, it is essentially De Morgan's Law.

Comment: @user253751 I missed your comment, but I just added the same thing as an answer.

Comment: The logical justification for "or" is that the sentence is a contraction of "... there is no institution which is *either* a university *or* a college". Saying "... there is no institution which is *both* a university *and* a college" means something different.

Comment: There is no university **nor** college

Comment: How would you normally express it in your mother tongue? Are the equivalent conjunctions "and" *and* "or" identical?

Comment: @Mari-LouA In Persian, we normally use "or" in this context. However, while we speak we can use both conjunctions with the same meaning based on the intonation. I mean I can chunk the words in a way that the first and the second sentences mean the same.  `In my city there is NO      university and college`. Actually I say "no" strongly and loudly to emphasis then hesitate before I say "university and college"

Comment: That piece of information would make a very interesting and valid addition to the question!

Comment: "no university and college" makes it sound like there is no thing that is both a university and a college.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The second version is correct although there are other alternatives. The first one doesn't mean what you want to convey.

So for the first one to have the meaning you want you need to repeat the "no":

> 1 . In my city there is no university and no college

And the second, while correct, can also be expressed as

> 2a. In my city there is neither a university nor a college
>
> 2b. In my city there is no university nor college

2b being less common - so you might be best sticking to your original 2

Comment: "Or" can definitely be used in negative phrases.

Comment: You're right! I'll edit

Comment: Also, "university and college" implies to me that they come in pairs.

Comment: 2a. probably requires an article: "In my city there is neither a university nor a college". 2b as well, for "college". I think "no" acts somewhat like a negative article here, so you need either "no" or "a".

Comment: "nor" is usually used along with "neither", e.g. "There is neither a university nor a college".

Comment: You can also say "there are neither universities nor colleges".

Comment: "nor" is quite unusual in normal speech even with "neither". I would generally recommend language learners always use "or"

Comment: "The second... can also be expressed as... nor" -- The first, too. [At least one dictionary defines "nor" as "and not" besides "or not".](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=nor)

Answer (score 8):

"*In my city there is no university **or** college*" is correct.

"*No college **or** university*" means the same as: "*both no college **and** no university*".

"*No college **and** university*" is awkward, and it means your city might have either a college or a university, but not both.

Answer (score 8):

This isn't really an English Language and Usage answer, but we do the same thing in formal logic, where it's called [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws): *(not A) and (not B)* is equivalent to *not (A or B)*.

Comment: English usage is not always consistent with mathematical logic. Students doing "word problems" in math sometimes discover this the hard way!

Comment: Indeed - and I see and hear lots of usages in English that don't follow the De Morgan's rules. But I think it works here.

Comment: Good thing this isn't the English Language and Usage site then. Phew!